# adding href link to a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I have sample dataframe 
Date Announcement href 
Apr 9, 2020 Hello World https://helloworld.com/

data = {'Date': ['c' , 'Apr 8,2010'], 'Announcement': ['Hello World A', 'Hello World B'], 'href': ['https://helloworld.com', 'https://helloworldb.com'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Announcement', 'href']
df.to_excel("announce.xls', engine='xlswriter')

I am trying to figure out how can i just have output in xls as following: dataframe in announcement column should have a link to href

Date Announcement
Apr 9, 2020 [Hello World](https://helloworld.com)

https://helloworld.com/

Answer (score 0):

Updated to your embed the url in the cell. The trick is to use the *.xslx format, as opposed to the 1997 *.xls format:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'Date': ['c' , 'Apr 8,2010'], 
        'Announcement': ['=HYPERLINK("http://helloworld.com", "Hello World A")','=HYPERLINK("http://helloworldb.com", "Hello World B")'], 
        } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Announcement']) 
df.to_excel('announce.xlsx')
```